How to install Winget in Azure pipelines on Windows 2022?
For some of my dependencies of my tests in Azure pipelines, I need Winget to install them.
I tried different approaches. For example by using this script, with this result:
##[error]Test-IsAdmin : The term 'Test-IsAdmin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\a\1\s\installwinget.ps1:2 char:11
+ if (-not (Test-IsAdmin)) {
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test-IsAdmin:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

and with this code
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/getwinget -OutFile winget.appinstaller.exe; Start-Process winget.appinstaller.exe

Having this result
##[error]Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The specified executable is not a valid application for 
this OS platform..
At D:\a\1\s\sqlserverinstall.ps1:23 char:83
+ ... utFile winget.appinstaller.exe; Start-Process winget.appinstaller.exe
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

I need something that works out the box and directly on Azure pipelines (windows-2022). I tried several other approaches. They all fail.

if you look at the response, its not an exe

Possibly, but feel free to provide a solution. As explained, I need something that works out of the box.


How to install Winget in Azure pipelines on Windows 2022?

To install Winget in Azure Pipelines, you need to refer to the following PowerShell script:
$progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'
Write-Information "Downloading WinGet and its dependencies..."
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/getwinget -OutFile Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx -OutFile Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/releases/download/v2.8.6/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.8.x64.appx -OutFile Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.8.x64.appx
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/download/v1.8.1522/cdc44a3f51ec4512b990fb5516afe12d_License1.xml -OutFile  cdc44a3f51ec4512b990fb5516afe12d_License1.xml

Add-AppxPackage Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx
Add-AppxPackage Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.8.x64.appx
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage  -Online -PackagePath Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle -LicensePath cdc44a3f51ec4512b990fb5516afe12d_License1.xml -Verbose

It will download/install the winget tool and configure the required license.
Pipeline sample:
steps:
- powershell: |
   
   $progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'
   Write-Information "Downloading WinGet and its dependencies..."
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/getwinget -OutFile Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx -OutFile Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/releases/download/v2.8.6/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.8.x64.appx -OutFile Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.8.x64.appx
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/releases/download/v1.8.1522/cdc44a3f51ec4512b990fb5516afe12d_License1.xml -OutFile  cdc44a3f51ec4512b990fb5516afe12d_License1.xml
   
   Add-AppxPackage Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.Desktop.appx
   Add-AppxPackage Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.8.x64.appx
   
   Add-AppxProvisionedPackage  -Online -PackagePath Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle -LicensePath cdc44a3f51ec4512b990fb5516afe12d_License1.xml -Verbose
   
   
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- powershell: |
   winget  --version 
   winget install vscode --silent --accept-package-agreements --accept-source-agreements
  displayName: 'Install VSCODE'

Result:

